# Solve logarithmic equation: $2\log_7 (x+2) - \log_7 (3x+10) = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Please, can someone check if
this is the right answer $$x= -2 \pm \sqrt{3x + 10}$$

Thank you.

Comment: No, that is not the right answer.  The answer would have the form x = (something not involving x).

Comment: Hint: If $2\log_7 (x+2) - \log_7 (3x+10)$ is equal to $0$, then $7^{2\log_7 (x+2) - \log_7 (3x+10)}$ must be equal to $7^0 = 1$.

Comment: Did not have a calculator for the test is it right til this point?

Comment: You need an answer of the form $x =$ number. Solving one of these is just another "solve for x" kind of problem.

Answer (score 3):

Let's rewrite the equation.
$$\begin{align}
2\log_7(x+2)-\log_7(3x+10) & = 0 \\
2\log_7(x+2) & = \log_7(3x+10) \\
\log_7\left((x+2)^2\right) & = \log_7(3x+10) \\
\implies (x+2)^2 & = 3x+10 \\
\end{align}$$
Now all we have to do is solve for $x$ in that equation.
$$\begin{align}
(x+2)^2 & = 3x+10 \\
x^2+4x+4 & = 3x+10 \\
x^2+x-6 & = 0 \\
(x+3)(x-2) & = 0 \\
\end{align}$$
$$x=-3, \ 2$$
However only $x=2$ is a solution, because $2\log_7(x+2)$ is not defined for $x=-3$. Therefore the solution is:
$$\color{green}{x=2}$$
Hope I helped

Answer (score 1):

Just for checking answers, I highly recommend Wolfram Alpha: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2log_7+%28x+%2B+2%29+-+log_7+%283x+%2B+10%29+%3D+0&x=0&y=0

Comment: Did not have a calculator for the test

Comment: And yet you just asked if that is the right answer, and the link answers, no. Certainly you can't expect people here to guess what your thoughts on the problem were. The more effort you show, more people will be inclined to help.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\log_7(x+2)^2-\log_7(3x+10) &= 0 \\ \\
\implies \log_7\frac{(x+2)^2}{(3x+10)} &= 0 \\ \\
\implies \frac{x^2+4x+4}{3x+10} &= 1 \\ \\
\implies x^2+4x+4 &= 3x+10 \\ \\
\implies x^2+x-6 &= 0
\end{align}$$

Solving for x will give you $x=-3$ and $x=2$. But only $2$ is acceptable as $\log_7(x+2)$ is not defined for $x=-3$.

Comment: What happened to your denominator 3x+10?

Comment: Cross multiplied with 1 and converted everything in a quadratic equation!